# in bash, counting the numbers of files that are grouped by score levels

Tags: linux, loops

I need to iterate over a directory.  Executing another written script on each file in the directory, and check if the output equals to any of five possible marks(`"A"`,`"B"`,`"C"`,`"D"`,`"F"`). The `for` loop aims to count how many files are in five mark categories respectively.

`$1`, `$2` are parameters for this script.
`$1` is the name of another written script, `$2` is the name of directory.

Here is part of my code.

```
for file in $(ls $2)
do
       if (( $($1 $file) == "A" ))
       then
            (( countA+=1 ))
       elif (( $($1 $file) == "B" ))
       then
            (( countB+=1 ))
       elif ((  $($1 $file) == "C" ))
       then
            (( countC+=1 ))
      
       fi
```

And the outcome is weird.

```
    A:100
    B:0
    C:0
    D:0
    F:0
```

It confuses me why all the 100 files in folder are marked as "A", in fact only 7 files are "A".

Comment: very good! And a well done with your code, very nicely indented, much easier to understand that way! But ... one thing, you'll need to also include a sample invocation from the command line, I see that you are doing `$($1 $file)` which I would interpert to mean that `$1` is a command like `sed` (or `cat`, or `wc` or ???), but without knowing how you call it, we can't really help. Add something like ./myScript wc` or whatever so we know how you are using it. ....

Comment: But is seems that you just want to count files that begin with `A`, etc. Its much better to use `case "${file}" in A* ) (( countA++ )) ;; B* ) ...... ;; C* ) .... ;; .......; esac`. Good luck.

Comment: And there are issues using `for file in $(ls $2) ; do ....` . Try `for file in $2 ; do...`. Other things too, did you paste your code into https://shellcheck.net ? Fix all errors/warnings found there. Good luck.

Comment: AND the best debugging tip (short off adding statements like `echo "file=|$file|   countA=|$countA| ..etc`, is to use the shell debug feature. near the top of your script, add a line `set -x` and you will see each line executed with the value of any variables substituted with the variable-name. You can turn it off with `set +x` . Good luck!

Comment: Arg, my first comment above (still remaining) has an error in it. Make you example usage to include a value for both `$1` and `$2`, so `./myScript wc *.zip` (just guessing here). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for shellcheck tip, really efficient way to debug. I tried  `for file in $2` , it 's safer. I would add meaning for $1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `(( == ))` does *numeric* comparison, but you're trying to compare strings (well, letters anyway). Suppose `$($1 $file)` evaluates to "B"; then the expression becomes essentially `(( B == A ))`, so the shell tries to turn both "A" and "B" into numbers so it can compare them. What it does is evaluate them as variable names, but `B` and `A` aren't defined, so both default to 0, and you have `(( 0 == 0 ))`... which is true. Essentially, no matter what `$1 $file` prints, it's going to match "A" because they both evaluate out to 0.

The quickest way to fix it is to use a string comparison instead (note: I'm also fixing some missing double-quotes):

```
if [[ "$($1 "$file")" = "A" ]]
```

A somewhat better solution would be to use `case`:

```
case "$($1 "$file")" in
    A) (( countA+=1 ));;
    B) (( countB+=1 ));;
    C) (( countC+=1 ));;
    D) (( countD+=1 ));;
    F) (( countF+=1 ));;
esac
```

But if you have bash v4 or later, it might be even simpler to use an associative array instead of separate variables for the counts:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A count=([A]=0 [B]=0 [C]=0 [D]=0 [F]=0)

for file in "$2"/*    # This is a better way to iterate over a directory's contents
do
    (( count["$($1 "$file")"] += 1 ))
done

for grade in A B C D F
do
    echo "$grade:${count[$grade]}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked! The string comparison solve my problem , I also find that `\`./$1 $file\`` with numeric comparison == could work.